# remove a word and its following line in linux using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to know how can I delete a word that begins with `* dd` and keep its current line but remove the following line.

I used this command to remove the word `sed "s/^\*.dd//" test.cbl > test.cbl.new` it turns up well but I can't remove the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^\*.dd/{s/^\*.dd//;n;d};' test.cbl > test.cbl.new
```

Will search for your pattern, then search and replace the pattern (`s///`) and and the delete the next line (`n;d`).

Comment: thanks for your answer, your code works very well and delete the next line but I want  to remove the pattern as well as its next line using one command

Comment: @malmo I edit my answer and added an awk solution too

Comment: thank you for your help I really appreciate it,  the awk code delete both lines, I want to delete the pattern but keep its current line and move to the next line and delete it  for example if I have in my file:                   *dd  hello world 
   thank you (it's the next line)   
the results would be 
hello world

Comment: thank you so much it works like a charm I really appreciate your help you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 'if (s/^\* dd//) { readline }' test.cbl
```

should do it. Or more compressed:

```
perl -pe '<> if s/^\* dd/' test.cbl
```